# JasperReport - subreport height dynamic

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I want to generate a pdf file with `JasperReport`, with **JasperSoft Studio 6.5**.

In my `jrxml` file I have  two level of subreports.

I have more difficult with the layout of this report. This report contains (*1° subreport*) a dynamic list of file (with a description field, which in some cases is very wordy).

The *2° subreport* is a list of files (composed by file name and note)

The row that contain the 1° subreport have a height dynamic in base of two criteria:

1. the description field
2. the number of the row conteined in the second subreport

If the 2° subreport is higher than the first, I have a problem if I have a page change.
Thus, if the first subreport is higher than the second, the second does not follow the height of the first.

It's not a simple problem to describe, I know. I hope the image can help you understand.

**CASE 1: Verbose description:**

[image: Case 1]

**CASE 2: Second subreport are divided over several pages**

[image: Case 2]

In my jrxml file I have used this:

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement key="" stretchType="ContainerHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="310" y="0" width="285" height="35" uuid="1b99fb4b-1bfd-4f88-8ef7-1568c6de04aa">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$FlistSource}.isEmpty()]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listSource})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+ "sub_filename.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

I don't find an elengant solution for this report,
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You want both tables to be the same size, even if one extends?

Setting both tables stretchtype to "RelativeToTallestObject" might work.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing change, I have the same behavior.